# Some files are shown as ignored in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

I am a new user in NetBeans. When I loaded my project, some files are faded. When I put the cursor there, it is showing the message `ignored`. Why it is so?

Comment: Can you name some example files?

Comment: all the jar files and class files are also ignored

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles on this question: the valid answer is here (same user asking the question again): [ignored files in the netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092072/ignored-files-in-the-netbeans)