# ignored files in the netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I am a new NetBeans user. When I loaded my project, some files are faded. When I put the cursor over them, they are showed as "ignored". Why? All the JAR files and class files are also ignored.

Comment: It's enough to ask once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091969/some-files-are-shown-as-ignored-in-netbeans

Comment: I am sorry. After that I didnt get any post.thats why. I am in work and I needed the answer. I am sorry if it irritate you

Answer (score 5):

Check Tools->Options->Miscellaneous->Files, there you can see what files are ignored by IDE and correct the settings if needed.

Comment: I got like this
 ^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!htaccess$).*$

Comment: Could be a bug, then. There's no other reason IDE would ignore files.

Comment: oh.. how can I solve it?Is this becoz of nay program error? I am sorry if it is a stupid question

Comment: Bugs should be fixed by NetBeans developers.

Answer (score 2):

"Ignored" in this context means files that are ignored by the VCS system.  With CVS, the ignored files and directories are stored in .cvsignore in each directory.  NetBeans manages this file automatically (you can right-click a file/directory and use CVS-> [Un]Ignore) to affect which are ignored.  You can ignore other directories (like a folder that contains generated sources) so you don't accidentally commit them to VCS.

When you create a new project, Netbeans automatically adds build, dist and nbproject/private directories to the .cvsignore file because it doesn't expect you to commit those to the VCS.

Answer (score 1):

I was just getting this with files in my mercurial repo. I had to just right-click them and select the 'Mercurial | Status' menu. When it refreshed the status, '[Ignored]' disappeared.

I did this after ensuring my .hgignore wasn't the culprit.